# How to format IPython html display of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas, ipython

How can I format IPython html display of pandas dataframes so that

1. numbers are right justified
2. numbers have commas as thousands separator
3. large floats have no decimal places

I understand that `numpy` has the facility of `set_printoptions` where I can do:

```
int_frmt:lambda x : '{:,}'.format(x)
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int_kind':int_frmt})
```

and similarly for other data types.

But IPython does not pick up these formatting options when displaying dataframes in html. I still need to have

```
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)
```

but with 1, 2, 3 as in above.

**Edit:** Below is my solution for 2 & 3 ( not sure this is the best way ), but I still need to figure out how to make number columns right justified.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
int_frmt = lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x)
float_frmt = lambda x: '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if x > 1e3 else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)
frmt_map = {np.dtype('int64'):int_frmt, np.dtype('float64'):float_frmt}
frmt = {col:frmt_map[df.dtypes[col]] for col in df.columns if df.dtypes[col] in frmt_map.keys()}
HTML(df.to_html(formatters=frmt))
```

Comment: You can also specify a list of formatters, with `None` values for those that are not present - which simplifies the `frmt` creation: `frmt = [frmt_map.get(dtype, None) for dtype in df.dtypes]`. +1 for the research.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

HTML receives a custom string of html data. Nobody forbids you to pass in a style tag with the custom CSS style for the `.dataframe` class (which the `to_html` method adds to the table).

So the simplest solution would be to just add a style and concatenate it with the output of the `df.to_html`:

```
style = '<style>.dataframe td { text-align: right; }</style>'
HTML( style + df.to_html( formatters=frmt ) )
```

But I would suggest to define a custom class for a DataFrame since this will change the style of all the tables in your notebook (style is "global").

```
style = '<style>.right_aligned_df td { text-align: right; }</style>'
HTML(style + df.to_html(formatters=frmt, classes='right_aligned_df'))
```

You can also define the style in one of the previous cells, and then just set the `classes` parameter of the `to_html` method:

```
# Some cell at the begining of the notebook
In [2]: HTML('''<style>
                    .right_aligned_df td { text-align: right; }
                    .left_aligned_df td { text-align: right; }
                    .pink_df { background-color: pink; }
                </style>''')

...

# Much later in your notebook
In [66]: HTML(df.to_html(classes='pink_df'))
```

Comment: If we mail this html, in the mail, HTML is not styled properly, any idea how to do it, sorry for resurrecting very old thread.

Comment: For the record, I think @JulienMarrec's [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40993135/5276797) below should be accepted now.

Answer (score 23):

This question was asked a long time ago. Back then, pandas didn't yet include [pd.Styler](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html). It was added in version `0.17.1`.

Here's how you would use this to achieve your desired goal and some more:

- Center the header
- right-align any number columns
- left-align the other columns.
- Add a formatter for the numeric columns like you want
- make it so that each column has the same width.

Here's some example data:

```
In [1]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3)*2000, columns=['A','B','C'])
df['D'] = np.random.randint(0,10000,size=10)
df['TextCol'] = np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 10)
df.dtypes

Out[1]:
A          float64
B          float64
C          float64
D            int64
TextCol     object
dtype: object
```

Let's format this using `df.style`:

```
# Construct a mask of which columns are numeric
numeric_col_mask = df.dtypes.apply(lambda d: issubclass(np.dtype(d).type, np.number))

# Dict used to center the table headers
d = dict(selector="th",
    props=[('text-align', 'center')])

# Style
df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns[numeric_col_mask], # right-align the numeric columns and set their width
                        **{'width':'10em', 'text-align':'right'})\
        .set_properties(subset=df.columns[~numeric_col_mask], # left-align the non-numeric columns and set their width
                        **{'width':'10em', 'text-align':'left'})\
        .format(lambda x: '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if x > 1e3 else '{:,.2f}'.format(x), # format the numeric values
                subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,df.columns[numeric_col_mask]])\
        .set_table_styles([d]) # center the header
```

[image: Result using pd.Styler]

---

Note that instead of calling `.format` on the subset columns, you can very well set the global default `pd.options.display.float_format` instead:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x: '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if x > 1e3 else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)
```

Comment: worth mentioning that `df.style.set_prop....render()` returns the desired html  while `df.to_html` does not.

Comment: Is there a way to set the table header alignment for individual columns as well? In particular to set it to right-aligned only for the columns which have right-aligned content?

Comment: This is a brilliant example which not only answers the question, but serves as a showcase for how to use the Style in Pandas. I wish their doc had something like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

On the OP's point 2:

> numbers have commas as thousands separator

pandas (as of 0.20.1) does not allow overriding the default integer format in an easy way. It is hard coded in [`pandas.io.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1957-L1962) (the `labmda` function):

```
class IntArrayFormatter(GenericArrayFormatter):

    def _format_strings(self):
        formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: '% d' % x)
        fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
        return fmt_values
```

I'm assuming is what you're actually asking for is how you can override the format *for all integers*: replace ("monkey patch") the `IntArrayFormatter` to print integer values with thousands separated by comma as follows:

```
import pandas

class _IntArrayFormatter(pandas.io.formats.format.GenericArrayFormatter):

    def _format_strings(self):
        formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: ' {:,}'.format(x))
        fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
        return fmt_values

pandas.io.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter = _IntArrayFormatter
```

**Note:**

- before 0.20.0, the formatters were in `pandas.formats.format`.
- before 0.18.1, the formatters were in `pandas.core.format`.

#### Aside

For floats you do not need to jump through those hoops since there is a [configuration option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) for it:

> `display.float_format`: The callable should accept a floating point number and return a string with the desired format of the number. This is used in some places like `SeriesFormatter`. See `core.format.EngFormatter` for an example.