# Formatting thousand separator for integers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `'{:,}'.format(number)` like the example below to format a number in a pandas dataframe:

```
# This works for floats and integers
print '{:,}'.format(20000)
# 20,000
print '{:,}'.format(20000.0)
# 20,000.0
```

The problem is that with a dataframe that has integers does not work, and in a dataframe with float works ok. See the examples:

```
# Does not work. The format stays the same, does not show thousands separator
df_int = DataFrame({"A": [20000, 10000]})
print df_int.to_html(float_format=lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x))

# Example of result
# <tr>
#   <th>0</th>
#   <td> 20000</td>
# </tr

# Works OK
df_float = DataFrame({"A": [20000.0, 10000.0]})
print df_float.to_html(float_format=lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x))

# Example of result
# <tr>
#   <th>0</th>
#   <td>20,000.0</td>
# </tr>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for integers, but can't you use a float and specify the precision, as in `{:,.0f}`?

Comment: you need to specify a separate formatter for int; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe) question for example.

Comment: But in that question he used the same format that I used `int_frmt = lambda x: '{:,}'.format( x )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `formatters` parameter in `to_html` will take a dictionary of column names mapped to a formatting function.  Below has an example of a function to build a dict that maps the same function to both floats and ints.

```
In [250]: num_format = lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x)

In [246]: def build_formatters(df, format):
     ...:     return {column:format 
     ...:               for (column, dtype) in df.dtypes.iteritems()
     ...:               if dtype in [np.dtype('int64'), np.dtype('float64')]}
     ...: 

In [247]: formatters = build_formatters(df_int, num_format)


In [249]: print df_int.to_html(formatters=formatters)
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>20,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>10,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 14):

pandas (as of 0.20.1) does not allow overriding the default integer format in an easy way. It is hard coded in [`pandas.io.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.1/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1957-L1962) (the `lambda` function):

```
class IntArrayFormatter(GenericArrayFormatter):

    def _format_strings(self):
        formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: '% d' % x)
        fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
        return fmt_values
```

I'm assuming what you're actually asking for is how you can override the format *for all integers*: modify (i.e. "monkey patch") the `IntArrayFormatter` to print integer values with thousands separated by comma as follows:

```
import pandas

class _IntArrayFormatter(pandas.io.formats.format.GenericArrayFormatter):

    def _format_strings(self):
        formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: ' {:,}'.format(x))
        fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
        return fmt_values

pandas.io.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter = _IntArrayFormatter
```

**Note:**

- before 0.20.0, the formatters were in `pandas.formats.format`.
- before 0.18.1, the formatters were in `pandas.core.format`.

#### Aside

For floats you do not need to jump through those hoops since there is a [configuration option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options) for it:

> `display.float_format`: The callable should accept a floating point number and return a string with the desired format of the number. This is used in some places like `SeriesFormatter`. See `core.format.EngFormatter` for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast your table to float64 and then use float_format as you like, especially if you are constructing a small table for viewing purposes. Instead of dealing with ints and floats separately this gives a quick solution.

`df.astype('float64',errors='ignore').to_html(float_format=lambda x: format(x,',.2f'))`

`errors='ignore'` is there to prevent raising an exception when a column can not be converted to floats, like strings.