# How to add thousand separator to numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, number-formatting, separator

Assuming that I have a pandas dataframe and I want to add thousand separators to all the numbers (integer and float), what is an easy and quick way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When formatting a number with `,` you can just use `'{:,}'.format`:

```
n = 10000
print '{:,}'.format(n)
n = 1000.1
print '{:,}'.format(n)
```

In pandas, you can use the `formatters` parameter to `to_html` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922609/formatting-thousand-separator-for-integers-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

```
num_format = lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x)
def build_formatters(df, format):
    return {
        column:format 
        for column, dtype in df.dtypes.items()
        if dtype in [ np.dtype('int64'), np.dtype('float64') ] 
    }
formatters = build_formatters(data_frame, num_format)
data_frame.to_html(formatters=formatters)
```

Adding the thousands separator has actually been discussed quite a bit on stackoverflow.  You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513615/add-decimal-mark-thousands-separators-to-a-number) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922609/formatting-thousand-separator-for-integers-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: It won't work with the dataframe that has integers. Only works for Float

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you just want to display (or render to html) the floats/integers with a thousands separator you can use [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) which was added in version 0.17.1:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'int': [1200, 320], 'flt': [5300.57, 12000000.23]})

df.style.format('{:,}')
```

To render this output to html you use the render method on the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler).

Comment: Using pandas 2.1.0 and Pycharm Pro this does work for floating numbers but neither for int32 nor for pd.Int64Dtype().

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742904):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map('{:,}'.format)
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x: f'{x:,}')
```

---

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply('{:,}'.format)
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:,}')
```

Comment: All 4 versions do change the dtype of the column to object which is not useful if you want to still be able to make calculations. (Pandas version: 2.1.0)

Answer (score 4):

Steps

- use `df.applymap()` to apply a function to every cell in your dataframe
- check if cell value is of type `int` or `float`
- format numbers using `f'{x:,d}'` for integers and `f'{x:,f}'` for floats

Here is a simple example for integers only:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: f'{x:,d}' if isinstance(x, int) else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want "." as thousand separator and "," as decimal separator this will works:

`Data = pd.read_Excel(path)`

`Data[my_numbers] = Data[my_numbers].map('{:,.2f}'.format).str.replace(",", "~").str.replace(".", ",").str.replace("~", ".")`

If you want three decimals instead of two you change "2f" --> "3f"

`Data[my_numbers] = Data[my_numbers].map('{:,.3f}'.format).str.replace(",", "~").str.replace(".", ",").str.replace("~", ".")`

Answer (score 1):

The *formatters* parameter in *to_html* will take a dictionary.

[Click the example link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922609/formatting-thousand-separator-for-integers-in-a-pandas-dataframe)