# Pandas df.to_html with CSS styling

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone please explain why the below outputs no data? The `Results.html` is not produced.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)
df.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
data = df.sort(ascending=True)
HTML('''<style>.white_space_df td { white-space: normal; }</style>''')
HTML(data.to_html(os.path.join(root, "Results.html"), index=False, na_rep="NA", classes='white_space_df'))
```

**Update**

I was able to work out the issue myself, just encase anyone else comes across this below is the working example.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root,filename), skip_blank_lines=True)
df.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
data = df.sort(ascending=True)
style = '''<style>.white_space_df td { word-wrap: break-word; }</style>'''
style + data.to_html(os.path.join(root, "Results.html"), index=False, na_rep="NA", classes='white_space_df')
```

Comment: are you sure you have data in df?

Comment: Yip works fine if I remove `HTML` just have `data.to_html(os.path.join(root, "Results.html"), index=False, na_rep="NA")` but of course im trying to add styling

Comment: What exactly is the `HTML` function you are using?

Comment: I found the idea here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Worked it out thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

The `to_html` method *saves* the html file (when passed a `buf` parameter), that is, it saves the xml to `Results.html`... and the method returns `None`.

```
data.to_html(os.path.join(root, "Results.html"), index=False, na_rep="NA", classes='white_space_df')
```

If you don't pass a `buf` argument (the first one) it returns a string:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df.to_html()
Out[12]: '<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>A</th>\n      <th>B</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

So you want to pass this string to HTML (rather than None):

```
HTML(data.to_html(index=False, na_rep="NA", classes='white_space_df'))
```

Comment: hmm I have already sorted this, I did post an update in my post no idea where thats gone. But im just about to head to bed, ill take a closer look once im not a zombie tomorrow err today err later. Thank Andy