# Edit HTML, inserting CSS reference

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pandas

It's possible to create HTML page from a CSV file, with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('../data.csv',delimiter=';', engine='python')
df.to_html('csv.html')
```

I would like to make that HTML to respect some CSS present in `csv.css`. One way to get this is to manually edit `csv.html` `head`, inserting:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csv.css"></head>
```

Instead of doing it manually, how one can get there programmatically (using Python)?

Comment: can you get some idea from this accepted SO here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_html` method does not output an entire HTML document. Instead, it just creates a single `table` element.

If you want to include CSS, you have to create additional HTML elements, and insert them yourself before writing the data. One of the simplest ways is as follows:

```
with open('test.html', 'w') as fobj:
    fobj.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"></head><body>')
    df.to_html(fobj)
    fobj.write('</body></html>')
```

The first argument of `to_html` has to be a file-like object: so it can be either a file object as in the above example or a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).