# How to set cell alignment in pandas dataframe.to_html()

Tags: html, pandas, html-table, justify

The official [document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) provided options to set cell alignment using `to_html(justify='left/right')` and it works. However, it is not clear how to justify non-header rows.

I've to use a hack to replace the HTML part

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'looooong_col':['1,234','234,567','3,456,789'],'short_col':[123,4,56]})
raw_html = df.to_html()
raw_html.replace('<tr>','<tr style="text-align: right;">')
```

So the modified html now is

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>looooong_col</th>
      <th>short_col</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1,234</td>
      <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>234,567</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>2</th>
      <td>3,456,789</td>
      <td>56</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and it rendered ok in http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ but not when I write it out to a html file, the cells are still left-justified.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try CSS. See my solution here. [Align text in Pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046215/how-to-align-pandas-dataframe-column-number-text-in-jinja)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Styler functionality.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
s = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'right'})
s.render()
```

s.render() returns a string of the generated CSS / HTML. Note the generated HTML will not be clean, as the internals declare a separate style for each cell.

Comment: more comprehensive setting see answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40993135/2944092

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'

Comment: Note that `Styler.render()` was deprecated in favour of `Styler.to_html()` as of pandas version 1.4.0. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html.html

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, and I notice you're asking about how to do this when your numbers are in string format, i.e. ['1,234','234,567','3,456,789']

If however, you just had floats or a mix of floats and strings in the pandas dataframe, one way to do this would simply be

```
df.to_html().replace('<td>', '<td align="right">')
```

Personally I needed to do this, since I had the following formatting I wanted to get out of the process above it:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
df.to_html().replace('<td>', '<td align="right">')
```

Does the job perfectly and doesn't mess with my formatting the way that using the Sty

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try to do the styling outside in the CSS instead.

If you're using [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) you will be unable to use Styler.

For example, you could add the following before your table HTML:

```
<style>
table {text-align: center;}
table thead th {text-align: center;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center align all values in the column, this worked for me

```
dict(selector="td", props=[("text-align", "center")])
```

Comment: Please clarify where to pass this dict.

Comment: @wlo Passing it to [`df.style.set_table_styles(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) should work.

Answer (score 1):

I like using the `classes` argument of `DataFrame.to_html()` in combination with some CSS for this type of task. In your case this could look something like this:

**CSS**

```
.my-table td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**pandas**

```
raw_html = df.to_html(classes=["my-table"])
```

**Output HTML**

```
<table class="dataframe my-table">
    ...
<table>
```

This lets you add HTML classes to the table element rendered by `DataFrame.to_html()`, leaving the styling to the frontend (that's what CSS is for after all).

Comment: CSS is the best solution. Note that each table gets a class="dataframe" by default. So one can set ` .dataframe {      text-align: right; } th {      min-width: 100px; }` in CSS.

Answer (score -7):

This did the trick for me

```
df.to_html(justify='left')
```

Comment: `df.to_html(justify='left')`, as stated in the original question, only works on the column headers, but not the rest of the dataframe.