# Pandas DataFrames in Jupyter: columns of equal width and centered

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Am using Jupyter Notebooks and would like to display a pandas DataFrame applying the same width to all the columns, with all values centered. What's the simplest way to achieve this, without importing libraries?

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Dragoons'], 
    'company': ['1st', '2nd'], 
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacob'], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df
```

[image: Unaligned columns]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

New in pandas 0.17.1 is the [`pd.Styler`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Precision):

```
raw_data= {'regiment': ['Nighthwawks','Dragons'],
            'company':['1st','2nd'],
            'name':['Miller', 'Ali'],
            'preTestScore':[4,120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

d = dict(selector="th",
    props=[('text-align', 'center')])

df.style.set_properties(**{'width':'10em', 'text-align':'center'})\
        .set_table_styles([d])
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to suggest you answer this [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe) too, but I see you already did. Upvoted!

Comment: Thank you @Julien, this is exactly what I needed. PS: I tried to add the code but could not find a way to display the output. This was the first time I use stackoverflow. Suggestions most welcome.

Comment: Format the output as code as well (indented by 4 spaces). Usually `print(df)` will do the job, just copy and paste that, then select your lines and click on the `{}` or press `CTRL`+`K`

Comment: @JulienMarrec is it ok to upload a picture in an answer?

Comment: If it's helpful sure?